# Logstash service not finding my json file

Tags: logstash, elk

i have an issue i can't figure out. I am also not sure how logstash **sincedb_path** works too so if someone could help me understand - I'd highly appreciate.

I am running ELK on RedHat Linux virtual  machine. If i am runing logstash file in terminal:

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash  -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/new.conf
```

everything works and I even see logs in kibana which is awesome btw.

However, if i try to run it as a service everything stops here with info logging option:

```
[2022-10-11T22:42:26,668][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2022-10-11T22:42:26,681][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

trace logging option gives me this:

```
[2022-10-11T23:16:07,000][TRACE][filewatch.discoverer     ][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] discover_files {:count=>0}
[2022-10-11T23:16:07,755][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2022-10-11T23:16:08,001][DEBUG][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] writing sincedb (delta since last write = 15)
[2022-10-11T23:16:08,001][TRACE][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] sincedb_write: /dev/null (time = 2022-10-11 23:16:08 +0300)
[2022-10-11T23:16:08,001][TRACE][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] non_atomic_write:  {:time=>2022-10-11 23:16:08 +0300}
[2022-10-11T23:16:09,888][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:09,888][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:12,755][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2022-10-11T23:16:14,892][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:14,892][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:17,755][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2022-10-11T23:16:19,896][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:19,896][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2022-10-11T23:16:22,005][TRACE][filewatch.discoverer     ][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] discover_files {:count=>0}
[2022-10-11T23:16:22,755][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2022-10-11T23:16:23,006][DEBUG][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] writing sincedb (delta since last write = 15)
[2022-10-11T23:16:23,006][TRACE][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][08eaaedb6ad66113aed8069a590d6833a9770ddcf4e214fd8b2500e546978c6e] sincedb_write: /dev/null (time = 2022-10-11 23:16:23 +0300)
```

which I guess means that it can't find my json file. and also
**writing sincedb (delta since last write = 15)** value doesn't
change.

new.conf:

```
input {
file {
path => "/home/mariussur/logstash/c.json"
codec => "json"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}

filter {}

output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["http://***.**.*.**:9200/"]
user => "*******"
password => "*******"
index => "some-tag"
action => "create"
}
}
```

pipelines.yml:

```
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"
```

I have tried changing ownership of files to logstash user  but still no luck.
Maybe someone had a similar issue and could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Comment: The message "discover_files {:count=>0}" means it found 0 files that match the path. Perhaps the /home/mariussur/logstash/ directory is not accessible by the user that is the service is running as.

Comment: You're right. @Badger

Putting the file in another path where the Logstash user have permissions to read it solved the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the logstash logs which you shared here, it is observerd that you logstash configuration "new.conf" is not running.

```
[2022-10-11T22:42:26,681][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```